# MongoDB Text search in 2 different languages

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, full-text-search, multilingual

Is there any easy way to perform just ONE query to get as result a text search for instance, in English and Spanish languages at the same time ?

as an example, I try to get both results just using one search:

```
db.myMultilingualData.find  ({ $text: { $search: "hi" , $language: "english"}})

db.myMultilingualData.find  ({ $text: { $search: "hola", $language: "spanish"}})
```

Thanks

Comment: that's the first restriction mentioned in documentation **A query can specify, at most, one $text expression.**

Comment: sure, you are absolutely right, that's why I try to figure out something like $search "hi" "hola" (so "or" is applied) but still restricting the languages to English and Spanish avoiding setting the language to "none"

Comment: i am afraid you may need to redesign your data model to have multilingual data, unless we could find some twisted way forward for this.

Comment: I appreciate your comments Jithin Scaria

Currently the model holds multilingual data. I was really curious if I could be missing an easy way to do that just in a unique simple step.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Probably $or operand could be your solution. I'm not sure at what level you would have to use it, but you can try it.